# maximum capacity of mongodb inside a docker container

Tags: mongodb, docker, containers, storage, capacity

Does anyone know about the maximum capacity of **mongodb** inside a docker container. I found maximum capacity of docker container is 10GB, is that right? and is that the capacity that mongodb can be scaled up to? any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can change `dm.basesize` in docker config.